# Using RequireJS to load files that are not required else where

Tags: javascript, requirejs, build-process, gruntjs, dependency-management

I'm currently building a massive web app that needs some sort of script dependancy loader. I started using RequireJS and found it's really great at optimising my code into one big JS file that loads in the correct dependancy order.

However I have plugins - these plugins are not required anywhere because my web-app doesn't know what plugins it has in the folders. What I would like is for the grunt-contrib-requirejs process is to:

1 - Take all my core files and load that into one file based upon their dependancies.

2 - Then I would like it to run over my two sets of plugin folders and load those in order based upon their dependancies.

3 - Then put those concatenated files into the first file so I have one JS file.

I have a Less and Handlebars process that searches through each Less/CSS/Handlebars files and sorts those out and I was wondering if there's anything like that for RequireJS?

Below is my grunt process for RequireJS:

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      name: "core/js/app",
      baseUrl: "src",
      mainConfigFile: "./config.js",
      out: "./build/adapt/js/adapt.min.js"
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my config.js file:

```
'use strict';

require.config({
deps: ['core/js/app'],
paths: {
    jquery: 'core/js/libraries/jquery.v2',
    underscore: 'core/js/libraries/underscore',
    backbone: 'core/js/libraries/backbone',
    modernizr: 'core/js/libraries/modernizr',
    handlebars: 'core/js/libraries/handlebars',
    imageReady: 'core/js/libraries/imageReady',
    inview: 'core/js/libraries/inview',
    scrollTo: 'core/js/libraries/scrollTo',
    coreJS: 'core/js',
    components: 'components'
},
shim: {
    jquery: [],
    backbone: {
        deps: ['core/js/libraries/underscore', 'core/js/libraries/jquery.v2'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    handlebars: {
        exports: 'Handlebars'
    }
}
});
```

I do confess to being pretty new to RequireJS so would be good to get some advice of pointers to a solution. But like I said above - I need a build process that doesn't go through a JSON list, but rather search through folders after the main core is optimised in the correct order.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. How are your plugins different to how you are loading Backbone, Underscore etc? Can you give an explanation why you would want Grunt to search through your folders instead of a JSON file? Also how are you planning on knowing the order the plugins should concatenate in?

Comment: The project needs to be able to search through a plugins folder and do some sort of require optimizer through these, because a developer can add a plugin into the folder - run the build process and expect the file to be added into the main JS file. We could create a JSON file and that would be fine to do - but I'm hoping there's another way to do that? As a developer we're trying to make it as simple as possible to add a plugin and not edit a JSON file. But maybe this is something we need to do?

Answer (score 0):

> As a developer we're trying to make it as simple as possible to add a
>   plugin and not edit a JSON file.

This is a problem solved by *documentation*, not automation. Adding a line to a require config is easier than writing a Grunt task to do the same automatically *and then maintaining that file*. Even if it were to be done automatically, how would you handle user defined configuration? Would it be a case of setting up some boilerplate that is then concatenated to with an automatically generated list of .js files in a certain directory? You'd *still* have to document this with `run grunt generaterequireconf` or something along those lines.

Just document the process for adding jQuery plugins: download, install to the specified directory, then add the path to the main JS file in the require config, here's the path to that.

What I would also say to do is to have a look at Bower, and see if you can get people using that to manage plugins made by third parties.